# How to log node.js on crash to a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, discord.js

I have a Discord Bot coded with Node.js.
I added a restart command into it when it crashes so I can maintain it on, but randomly every 2-3 times in 24 hours it just restarts.

It might be worth mentioning that I am using replit hacker plan to host it for now.

I don't know -the reason yet, so what I want to do is:

I want to export the traceback/error log into a text file or anything similar so when it crashes I can go through it and try to debug.

Is there an actual way to do so?

I looked for some different ways online and I found this but it didn't seem to work for me since the bot restarted twice this night and no logs.
I might just don't know how to use it properly though.

Please help me!

```
const util = require('util');
const fs = require('fs');
var log_file_err=fs.createWriteStream('./logs/error.txt',{flags:'a'});  

process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
console.log('Caught exception: ' + err);
log_file_err.write(util.format('Caught exception: '+err) + '\n');
});
```

Comment: Could it be that instead of `uncaughtException` an `unhandledRejection` is triggered instead? See https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#event-unhandledrejection

Comment: @eol

you have a point, should i just copy paste it with "unhandeledRejection" to try and catch both?



`origin <string> Indicates if the exception originates from an unhandled rejection or from synchronous errors. Can either be 'uncaughtException' or 'unhandledRejection'. The latter is only used in conjunction with the --unhandled-rejections flag set to strict or throw and an unhandled rejection.`